# Compiling against libwireshark

Tags: gcc, glib, wireshark, gcc-warning

I am attempting to compile a program against `libwireshark` on Ubuntu 10.10. I have installed the `wireshark-dev` package, which has installed files in `/usr/lib/wireshark` and `/usr/include/wireshark`.

The head of my C source code file contains a `#include <epan/epan.h>` directive and my `gcc` command line arguments are as follows:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/include/wireshark `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0` -Wall -o test.out test.c -L/usr/lib/wireshark -lwireshark
```

However, this returns many errors, including:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include/varargs.h:4: error: #error "GCC no longer implements <varargs.h>."
/usr/include/wireshark/epan/ftypes/ftypes.h:258: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘union’
```

What should I do to rectify these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a simple case of user-unfriendly packaging and code organization.  You need to include the "config" header for Wireshark first.  I would write it this way:

```
#include <wireshark/config.h> /* needed by epan */
#include <epan/epan.h>
```

Be sure that you do this first whenever you include headers from this library.

How did I know?  I dug into `epan/proto.h` and found that it conditionally includes `varargs.h` only if `HAVE_STDARG` is not set.  I then `grep`'d in `/usr/include/wireshark/` and found this variable is set in `config.h`, so I figured it might be necessary to include it, and lo, it was.

I also needed to add `-lwiretap` to satisfy linkage with `libwireshark`.

Another nit in the organization of `wireshark-dev` is that it does not depend (at the package level) on `wireshark-common`, even though the latter does provide the actual `libwireshark.so` which the former symlinks to.  So you should make sure that `wireshark-common` is installed, or that `/usr/lib/libwireshark.so` and its referent exist.

Comment: You, sir, are a champion! Thank you very much. All the correct files seem to be in place (perhaps from previous attempts), but it's good to leave that there for posteriority.